# The JAR file C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar no source attachment

Tags: ide, eclipse, java

Когда в `Eclipse` нажимаю `ctrl + клик` на системный класс например, на `String`, то появляется сообщение что исходник не найден по пути `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar`

Зашел в `Window / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs` и добавил и выбрал JDK - `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10`

Но исходник все равно не находится. Где еще надо сделать изменения?

Answer (score 2):

1. Скачиваем последний JDK с [офф. сайта](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#javasejdk) и устанавливаем
2. Запускаем Eclipse, заходим Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs, жмём кнопку Add и указываем путь до JRE (в нашем случае внутри установленной папки с JDK, по умолчанию что-то вроде C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre)
3. В поле JRE system libraries выделяем все библиотеки (ctrl+a) и жмём кнопку Source attachment..., переключаемся на пункт External location, жмём кнопку External File и указываем файл src.zip (он находится в корне папки с установленным JDK)

Если JRE уже установлена и есть в списке, то необязательно добавлять новую, можно просто отредактировать указав для всех библиотек source attachment... src.zip из папки с jdk

Answer (score 1):

Так будет работать

[How to attach source in eclipse for Jars, debugging and code look-up – JDK Example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-attach-source-in-eclipse-Jar-JDK-debugging.html).